# Trying to launch a VirtualBox machine inside a VirtualBox machine with Vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm trying to create with Vagrant + VirtualBox an Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine (let's name it VM2) inside another Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine (VM1). I installed successfully Vagrant and VirtualBox in VM1, but when I'm launching the virtual machine VM2 using `vagrant up` inside VM1 I have the following error:

```
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

Finally it stops booting and I'm not able to create the virtual machine. I saw in VirtualBox forums that is possible to do it, but you mustn't use Virtualization Extensions (AMD-V, VT-X) inside a virtualized server (see [this](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=20589)). I disabled this extensions using the following commands:

```
$ VBoxManage modifyvm VM2 --hwvirtex off
$ VBoxManage modifyvm VM2 --vtxvpid off
$ VBoxManage modifyvm VM2 --vtxux off
```

But if I try to boot VM2 it's still not working.

At the beginning I was using an Ubuntu-64 box for VM2 but I have read that this extensions must be turned on if you want to boot a 64 bits machine, so my next step was trying to boot an Ubuntu 12.04-i386 box for VM2 but I obtained the same results (`default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...`). I tried also disabling the AMD-V / VT-X extensions in the 32 bits box but I'm having the same error all the time.

What can I try? Is it possible to boot my virtual machine VM2 inside VM1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested Virtualization (VM inside a VM) is **not** supported by VirtualBox.

See [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032) open feature request.

Comment: This feature request has lots of updates.  It's considered essential now.

Answer (score 0):

It's now supported!  See the [referenced feature request](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032) cited by m1keil:

Over 11 years is goes from "silly" to "essential" and now implemented for Intel chips.

Sorry not for AMD chips yet I guess. Because I need to do the same thing on an AMD 64 bit VM but it creates only a 32 bit machine for the 2nd VM.